# Google Chrome on Mac: how to force link to open in new window (not new tab)?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

How can I get links (boh from web pages within Chrome AND from external apps) to open in a new window rather than in a new tab in the active window?

This has been answered for Windows, but I cannot find a solution for Mac.

Comment: I found this for external links, this solution works:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9500/how-to-make-chrome-open-a-new-window-for-external-links

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Mac, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + left click open a link on webpage in a new window.

Comment: Shift+left click to open a link in a new window only works for links in the Chrome browser. Not from links in external applications

Comment: I was researching a slightly different question, "[Is it possible to force a Mac *.webloc file to open in a new Chrome window instead of a new tab in an existing window?][1]", and got an answer there using Automator that works for me with `.webloc` files.

The accepted answer above only works within web pages. The original question included external apps as well, and this Automator solution may be of help in that case.


  [1]: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400052/is-it-possible-to-force-a-mac-webloc-file-to-open-in-a-new-chrome-window-inste