# Is it possible to force a Mac *.webloc file to open in a new Chrome window instead of a new tab in an existing window?

Tags: mac, google-chrome

There is an answer already to a similar question that does work when the link is on a Chrome webpage, Shift + Left Click.

Unfortunately, Left Click does not work for me opening a `.webloc` file on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 with Chrome 84. It opens as a new tab in the most recently used Chrome window.

I'm interested in the answers offered at [How to make Chrome open a new window for external Links](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9500/how-to-make-chrome-open-a-new-window-for-external-links). Unfortunately Comment 1 on the question says "this solution works" but other users report there that one or another of the multiple solutions on that page do not work for them.

In addition, the most recent version of Chrome mentioned in those answers is Chrome 45 and we're nearly 40 versions past that to date. So I'm asking if anyone knows of something that works, rather than experimenting with complicated, programming solutions that are already identified as not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option to consider...

Use an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*<sup>1</sup>, via **Finder**, to open the **URL** contained in the **.webloc** *file* in a new *window* of **Google Chrome**.

<sub><sup>1</sup> In **macOS Mojave**, and later, an **Automator** *Service* is called a *Quick Action*. The use of *terms* separated with a **/** is to denote the differences between **Automator** prior to **macOS Mojave** and from it onwards.</sub>

The **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* can be triggered from the **Services** *context menu* via *right-click* (option-click) on the selected **.webloc** *file(s)* in **Finder**, or after selecting the **.webloc** *file(s)* in **Finder** press the *keyboard shortcut* assigned to the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*.

- In **Automator** create a new *Service/Quick Action*, setting: **Service/Workflow receives/receives current [files or folders] in [Finder]**
- Add a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the *default code* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with i from 1 to the length of input
        set thisItem to the POSIX path of item i of input
        if thisItem ends with ".webloc" then
            set dssCommand to ¬
                "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print :URL\" " & ¬
                quoted form of thisItem
            set thisURL to do shell script dssCommand
            if thisURL starts with "http" then
                tell application "Google Chrome"
                    set the URL of the active tab of ¬
                        (make new window) to thisURL
                end tell
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end run
```

- Save the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, e.g.: **Open webloc in Google Chrome**
- Add a *keyboard shortcut* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, e.g.: **⌘G**

---

**Notes:**

Depending on how the **.webloc** *file* was created, it can be either a *binary* **PLIST** *file* or an **XML plist** *text file*. The examples below shows `https://www.google.com/` as the **URL**:

[image: binary .webloc file in hex editor]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>https://www.google.com/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Regardless, the *example* **AppleScript** *code* uses a `do shell script` *command* to assign the *value* of the **URL** to a *variable* by using **PlistBuddy** to *print* the *value* of **URL** in the **.webloc** *file*. It then opens the **URL** in a new *window* in **Google Chrome**.

The **PlistBuddy** full output for the example **.webloc** *file*, in both forms, above is:

```
Dict {
    URL = https://www.google.com/
}
```

However, when configuring it to *print* the **URL** directly, its output for the example **.webloc** *file*, in both forms, above is just:

```
https://www.google.com/
```

As coded, it can handle multiple selected **.webloc** *files* opening each in its own window, regardless of how the *preferences* are set in **Google Chrome**. It validates that the *file(s)* passed to the *service* have a  **.webloc** *file extension*, and the *value* of the `thisURL` *variable* starts with `http`, otherwise the *service* fails silently.

---

<sup>This **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* was tested and worked for me, under **macOS High Sierra** and **macOS Catalina**, using both the **Services** *context menu* and **⌘G** assigned *keyboard shortcut* of the *service* on the selected **.webloc** *file(s)* in **Finder**.</sup>

Comment: Thank 894. (May I call you "894"? That seems so much more personal than "@user".)

On first reading, this looks complete and thorough. I can't wait to try it out, but unfortunately I may have to for a few days.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I finally got time to implement and test it. As the Brits say, "It works a champ!"

Thanks! As a Technical Writer, I appreciate all the tutorial detail too.